# mySQL query will not return results equal date

Tags: mysql, date

The following should find me the elector ID and the date. For some reason it does not seam to recognise the date and won't match any of them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `voting_intention` 
WHERE  `elector` =  '119'
AND  `election_date` =  '05-07-2012'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Why is this and how do we fix it.

Comment: What is the type of `election_date` in your database?

Comment: Please show some example dates.

Comment: @RobinKnight : how date is stored in your database then? What do you get `SELECT election_date FROM voting_intention`??

Comment: As you've told `election_date` is a varchar. Maybe there ar spaces before/after the actual text (date in your case) in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `voting_intention` 
WHERE  `elector` =  '119'
AND  `election_date` =  '2012-07-05'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Date format should be `yyyy-mm-dd`

### Update 1

Per your update, datatype of `election_date` is `varchar`.

If your date are in consistent format like say `yyyy-mm-dd` then use above query.

If its in format of `dd-mm-yyyy` then your query should work.

You will need to tweak the condition as per the format that you have.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `voting_intention` 
WHERE  `elector` =  '119'
AND  `election_date` =  'dateFormat'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

***Disadvantage of `varchar` for date is that you can't get data when your condition says >, >=, <, <=.***

*For date always use **[timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)**.*

Answer (score 0):

there might be some invisible characters in the db, like \r or \n or space... check this out first. try to use [trim](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to make sure that the characters get removed:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `voting_intention` 
WHERE  `elector` =  '119'
AND  TRIM(election_date) =  '05-07-2012'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```